# pyqt5でQLineEditのテキストが変化したときに即座にラベルのテキストを変化させたい

Tags: python3, pyqt5

pyqt5を使っています。QLineEditのテキストが変化したときに別に用意したラベルのテキストが変化するようにしたいです。次は試しに書いてみたコードです。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import *



class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self,title, parent):
        super().__init__(title,parent)


    def textChanged(self,e):
        pass


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        font=QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)

        self.edit1=LineEdit("",self)
        self.edit1.setFont(font)
        self.edit1.setText("860")

        self.lbl1=QLabel("860")
        self.lbl1.setFont(font)

        layout1=QVBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(self.edit1)
        layout1.addWidget(self.lbl1)

        self.setLayout(layout1)



        self.setWindowTitle('ラベル変化')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 100)


    def write_lbl(self):
        val=self.edit1.text()
        self.lbl1.setText(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

これを実行することで次のようなGUIが作成されます。
[image: 画像]

ここで、QLineEditのテキストを編集したときに、ラベルの文字が一緒に編集されるようにしたいです。最初のLineEditのクラスの中でtestChangedの関数を使えば出来そうな気がしましたが、いまいちよく分かりませんでした。ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 追記しました。確認をお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        font=QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)

        self.edit1=LineEdit("",self)
        self.edit1.setFont(font)
        self.edit1.setText("860")

        self.lbl1=QLabel("860")
        self.lbl1.setFont(font)

        layout1=QVBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(self.edit1)
        layout1.addWidget(self.lbl1)

        self.setLayout(layout1)
```

の中に、

```
self.connect(self.edit1,QtCore.SIGNAL("textEdited(QString)"),self.write_lbl)
```

を入れてみてください。もちろん、`self.edit1`オブジェクトを作成した後にお願いします。
私は`PySide`で試したのですが、これで動きました。`PyQt5`だと若干挙動が異なる可能性がありますから、もし何かありましたらコメントで教えてください。

**追記**

```
self.edit1.textEdited.connect(self.write_lbl)
```

こっちにしてみてください。急遽`PyQt5`に切り替えてみたら、最初のではエラーが出ました。
だいぶ変わっていますね。失礼しました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！無事に動作してくれました。わざわざクラスで分ける必要なかったんですね。

Comment: @toma シグナルとスロットは非常に便利ですが、書き方が特殊な設計がなされています。パターンはいくつもあり、ウィジェットに何らかのアクションを加えたときが基本とすると、全く無関係なところからコーディングの事情により、シグナルを発射すること、シグナルでシグナルを発射する等、結構奥が深いです。Qtをされていらっしゃるなら、このシグナル＆スロットはぜひ細部まで熟知されることをお勧めいたします。コードが非常に短く済むことが多いです。

Comment: わざわざクラスで分ける必要はない。その通りです。デフォルトで備わっているシグナルだからです。逆にあのように関数を作ってしまうと、関数の名前とシグナルの名前が衝突してしまい、エラーが発生してしまいます。今回は`textEdited`の方だったので、衝突はしませんでした。自分で自前のシグナルを作成することももちろんできますよ。

Comment: 詳しい解説ありがとうございます！まだまだ未熟者ですが頑張ってみます。

Comment: ちなみにですが、PySideだと追加前でも追加後でも動きます。私もまだひよっこです。たまたま今回は知っていただけですね。